# LSTM model prints trailing garbage characters

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm training a seq2seq model for spelling correction, adapted from https://github.com/MajorTal/DeepSpell.

My model learns reasonably well how to correct spelling mistakes, but for some reason it prints trailing nonsense characters as well. For example:

Typo: A few fresh cZhives for garnish

Correct: A few fresh chives for garnish

Prediction: A few fresh chives for garnishhngghnnn))))))ssssssssssssssss

The architecture for the model in Keras is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()

# Add masking layer
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, len(chars))))

# "Encode" the input sequence using an RNN, producing an output of hidden_size
# note: in a situation where your input sequences have a variable length,
# use input_shape=(None, nb_feature).
for layer_number in range(CONFIG.input_layers):
    model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, input_shape=(None, len(chars)), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization,
                             return_sequences=layer_number + 1 < CONFIG.input_layers))
    model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))
# For the decoder's input, we repeat the encoded input for each time step
model.add(RepeatVector(output_len))
# The decoder RNN could be multiple layers stacked or a single layer
for _ in range(CONFIG.output_layers):
    model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization))
    model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))

# For each of step of the output sequence, decide which character should be chosen
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Resolved. I inserted a trailing end of sequence character to punctuate the end of each sequence in training and the model learned how to end sequences by inserting end of sequence characters at prediction time.